# Port VS2010 CodeGenerator extension to VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, vsix

I'm trying to port a Visual Studio 2010 originally developed Single File Code Generator extension to Visual Studio 2013. The extension (vsix format) consists in 2 item templates and the actual generator project. The generator is based on the "IVsSingleFileGenerator". Everything works just fine in visual studio 2010: when i add an item of the type of one of my 2 item templates, visual studio triggers the code generator, which does his job. Now, i edited the vsixmanifest file of the generator project adding the compatibility with visual studio 2013, and so i'm capable at least of installing the extension into visual studio 2013. The 2 item templates also work just fine in vs2013, but the generator doesn't. If i force the triggering by right-click on the file and then "run custom tool" then i get a messagebox saying "Cannot find custom tool 'myGenerator' on this system". This is weird since all my components are set to ComVisible(true). I think there must be some difference in how vs2013 manages his extensions respect to vs2010. Does anyone of you know something about? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `[ProvideBindingPath]` attribute so Visual Studio can locate the generator within your assembly. An example of the steps to use this attribute can be seen in this commit:

https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/VsixWizardSample/commit/ed7f142ad1c2b631c996cda67f43d348814c0a66

Comment: Thank you soooo much!! It did the work! You saved me :D